# Visualisation of relationships between different classes and interfaces in a Java framework

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

I'm currently learning Java concurrency framework, I had the same problem a while back while learning Java collection framework. At the beginning, I had trouble understanding the relationship between different classes and interfaces in the same framework.

So I was just wondering is there anyway that can help me visualise those relationships?

Comment: One of great books on the java concurrency subject is "java concurrency in practice", please read this book and ask questions if there will be something ambiguous to you.

Comment: I'm currenlty reading that book, i guess my question is more towards is there a way to map relationships between classes and interfaces in a framework.

Comment: You mean to visualize the concurrency class diagram? You can use your imagination or ask google about it, google for "java concurrency class diagram"

Comment: thank you, have been looking for the diagram but using the wrong keywords, that's why google wouldn't give me what i was looking for. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, it's sometimes hard to explain what you are asking for, especially to form a valid question for google. I have same problem lot of times :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to visualize the concurrency class diagram, then you could use your imagination or ask google about it, google for "java concurrency class diagram"